# Running JProfiler for grails on IntelliJ

Tags: performance, jprofiler

I am trying to run JProfiler for grails application. I would really appreciate any suggestions with the following:
1) Since I don't have an explicit class with main() method in grails application, I am assuming Attaching to a running JVM is my only option. Is that true? Is there a way I could attach JProfiler before the grails application starts?
2) After attaching to a running JVM, what does JProfiler need inorder to profile the controller/service/src/domain files. Do I have to execute the test cases. In my case they are rest controllers so do I have to run the requests for all possible scenarios?
3) Is it possible to have the Jprofiler profile the code without me running the test cases, since I may not be able cover all scenario's?

Answer (score 1):

> Since I don't have an explicit class with main() method in grails application

A JVM profiler does not depend on a main method that is written by yourself. The only thing you have to be able to do is to pass the `-agentpath` VM parameter to the JVM. The exact parameter is given by `Session->Integration wizard->New Remote Integration` in JProfiler and has to be added to the environment variable `GRAILS_FORK_OPTS` for Grails >= 3.1.5.

The Intellij IDEA integration can profile Grails run configurations directly, so you don't have to do the above.

Using the attach API is also possible, but has a higher overhead when connecting and prevents some profiling capabilities from being enabled.

> do I have to run the requests for all possible scenarios

The profiler profiles the entire JVM, so whatever use case you run while profiling will show up in the profiler.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response Ingo. "The Intellij IDEA integration can profile Grails run configurations directly, so you don't have to do the above. " How could I do this so that I could profile the application startup?

Comment: Install the JProfiler plugin in IDEA select the grails run configuration and click on the profile button in the tool bar. In the session startup dialog in JProfiler, select a recording profile that includes CPU profiling. Then it profiles the entire startup of the application server.

Comment: I am getting the following error on click of the profile button in the tool bar: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "kotlin.reflect.KClasses.getMemberProperties(Lkotlin/reflect/KClass;)Ljava/util/Collection;" the class loader (instance of com/intellij/ide/plugins/cl/PluginClassLoader) of the current class, com/jprofiler/integrations/idea/runner/f, and the class loader (instance of com/intellij/util/lang/UrlClassLoader) for the method's defining class, kotlin/reflect/KClasses, have different Class objects for the type kotlin/reflect/KClass used in the signature

Comment: I will post the complete stack trace in the answer section due to the character restriction for comments

Comment: In stackoverflow, you should not post answers with more information or switch to a different issue in the same question, I would recommend to delete your answer. Since I will have to provide you with a new build, please send the stack trace to support@ej-technologies.com together with the IDEA version number that you are using.

Comment: Sure. I have deleted the error log and sent the stack trace to support email. Your quick response is much appreciated.